# why soundex return irrelevant result

Tags: sql, soundex

I wonder why :

```
  WHERE 1=1 
    AND   LTRIM(RTRIM(lastName)) ='Schmdli' 
        OR ( 
                SOUNDEX(lastName) = SOUNDEX('Schmdli')
            )
```

Return me result like

```
lastName
Schöntal
Schindler-Külling
Schindler
Schmidlin
Schindler
Schmidli
Schmidli
Schindler
```

while I expect only:

```
Schmidli
Schmidli
Schmidlin
```

My first  `AND   LTRIM(RTRIM(lastName)) ='Schmdli'` is to match exact value then with soundex I expect better near Schmdli result here some result like

```
Schöntal
Schindler-Külling
Schindler
```

shouldn't appear.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Trivial answer: because `SOUNDEX` is a [simple algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#American_Soundex) with limited space (one letter and three digits), and all of your examples happen to translate to the same one, `S534`, only taking into account the letters S, C, M and D. Incidentally, Schöntal only takes into account S, C, N and T, producing the same output since M and N encode in the same way, as do D and T.

Comment: Plus it is a US-English based algorithm that may not work great with other languages, such as German

Comment: ok thanks got it, so what should be the right way to achieve my request ?

Comment: `lastName LIKE 'Schmidli%'`?

Comment: not the solution, i want "best near result" not exact result

Comment: In that case, look for a phonetic hashing algorithm better than soundex. SO is not for recommending libraries, but you can take a look [here](https://yomguithereal.github.io/talisman/phonetics/). I'd suggest you add a column to your database containing the hash so that you don't destroy your indices by calculating the hashes at index-time (and to also allow you to use non-SQL implemention of the hashing algorithm). Hash the field when you `INSERT`, and hash the query before you `SELECT`. I personally like the sound of eudex.

Comment: Soundex was invented before digital computers, and designed to help the Census Bureau identify people.  If you are going to use the algorithm, learn a bit about its history:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex.